# Please Help me to understand old C code

Tags: c, audio, turbo-c

I'm student and found this code on Internet. Can anyone explain algorythm used here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int count=50;
    clrscr();
    while(count--)
    {
        sound(10*random(100));
        delay(75);
        nosound();
        textattr(random(16)+'a'+BLINK);
        cprintf("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is sound()? What does delay function do, delay for ms or second or micro second? What is nosound?

Comment: I don't know actually ..I just tun it in turbo C and amazed .... polyphonic tones came out ...

Comment: http://eforengineers.blogspot.in/2013_08_13_archive.html

Comment: can you let us know what you are trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Turbo C code. `sound` will set the "PC beeper" playing given frequency, so the code will produce 50 random tones in the loop. It will also use `textattr` to select random color (most common text modes had 16 fixed colors, `random(16)` is for that reason) with blink attribute set and print an asterisk 50 times along with the sounds. This will require a real DOS text mode which actually supports blinking characters, in modern console window there will be no blinking.

Also, the include files and libraries are not standard C libraries, so basically code requires Turbo C to work without modification. The code is from simpler era of PC software, where applications had entire computer for themselves, and often used text mode.

Comment: hmmm... yea thanks but ..i know while(such as a==5) or while (any kinds of relation ) but how "while (count--) " works ;

Comment: Ah. Well, that is pretty basic C... It first uses the current value of `count`, then *post-decrements* `count`. Here value is used in condition, 0 is false and all other values are true.